# How to convert List<Optional<Type>> into List<Type>

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have extracted values from a `Map` into a `List` but got a `List<Optional<TXN_PMTxnHistory_rb>>`, and I want to convert it into `List<TXN_PMTxnHistory_rb>`.

My code:

```
List<Optional<TXN_PMTxnHistory_rb>> listHistory_rb6 = 
    listHistory_rb5.values()
                   .stream()
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'd like to obtain a `List<TXN_PMTxnHistory_rb>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Filter out all the empty values and use `map` to obtain the non-empty values:

```
List<TXN_PMTxnHistory_rb> listHistory_rb6 = 
    listHistory_rb5.values()
                   .stream()
                   .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                   .map(Optional::get)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do this using a method called `flatMap` on the stream of `Optional`s which will remove any 'empty' `Optional`s.

```
List<TXN_PMTxnHistory_rb> listHistory_rb6 = 
    listHistory_rb5.values()
                   .stream()
                   .flatMap(Optional::stream)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Flatmap is essentially performing two things - "mapping" and "flattening". In the **mapping** phase it calls whatever method you've passed in and expects back a new stream - in this case each `Optional` in your original `List` will become a `Stream` containing either 1 or 0 values.

The **flatten** phase will then create a new `Stream` containing the results of all the mapped `Stream`s. Thus, if you had 2 `Optional` items in your `List`, one empty and one full, the resulting `Stream` would contain 0 elements from the first mapped `Stream`, and 1 value from the second.

Comment: Note that `Optional.stream()` requires Java 9.

Comment: My preferred solution, and well explained too. A well-deserved upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to get all values and then filter out `nulls`:

```
List<TXN_PMTxnHistory_rb> listHistory_rb6 =
        listHistory_rb5.values().stream()
                       .map(opt -> opt.orElse(null))
                       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @AndrewTobilko thanks, missed it. Changed to `opt -> opt.orElse(null)`